# Android Broadcast Receiver in Widget

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to register for a broadcast receiver from within a widget? I have tried a few ways and the registration seems to work but the widget is never called back when the event occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to register for a broadcast receiver from within a widget?

No, sorry. Whatever problem you are trying to solve this way can either be solved a better way or should not be solved.

Comment: If I need a widget that receives broadcast (of the kind that have to be registered in code, not in the manifest).. do I HAVE to use a service?

Answer (score 0):

A widget basically is a broadcast receiver, so if you want to you can statically define intent filters in your widget's AppManifest.xml and handle the broadcast intents in your widget's onReceive() method as shown here:

[android update widget from broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545773/android-update-widget-from-broadcast-receiver)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, for example: http://madandroid.blogspot.com/2011/05/registering-broadcast-receiver-from.html

Note that the BroadcastReceiver and not the widget will be called when the event occurs.

Comment: @metalideath: This is completely unreliable. Android will terminate your process whenever it wants after the `onUpdate()` method returns, causing the `BroadcastReceiver` and `Application` to both vanish.

Comment: That would explain some of the weird behavior that I have been seeing.